# НЕ подключается CSS файл к HTML

Tags: html, css

**Проблема** заключается в том, что я не могу подключить CSS файл к HTML

**Код написан верно** - я всё проверял по несколько раз.

Пользуюсь Sublime Text

```css
body {
 background-color: #red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>ds</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">3 колонки</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">7 колонок</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">2 колонки</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Папка app в которой находится index.html*[image: Папка app в которой находится index.html]

*Папка css в которой находится style.css*[image: Папка css в которой находится style.css]

*CSS/HTML в редакторе*[image: CSS/HTML в редакторе]

Я не знаю, что делать, прошу помощи на форуме, ничего не помогает, сижу третий час за этой проблемой.

ps: Если вписать style в html файл, то всё будет работать.

Сам css файл не битый, и отображается в браузере
[image: Файл css в браузере]

Comment: не #red а просто red

Answer (score 3):

> Код написан верно - я всё проверял по несколько раз.

Неверно, ошибка в коде.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style/style.css">` вы подключаете файл котрый должен быть в папке `style` которая находится в папке `css`.

Хотя сам файл просто в папке `css`.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

**UPD.** Вторая ошибка в файле css. Уберите хеш перед значением свойства
`background-color: red`.

Comment: Исправил, но всё равно не помогло.

Comment: @memberzz  я же написал выше - где у вас ошибка

Comment: @memberzz, у вас в ссылке `/style` лишнее.